# When I make custom cluster marker on google map via swiftUI, create class CustomClusterRenderer: GMUDefaultClusterRenderer

Tags: swift, google-maps, swiftui, cluster-computing, renderer

To override the renderer `GMUDefaultClusterRenderer` use the following code:

```swift
class CustomClusterRenderer: GMUDefaultClusterRenderer {
    override func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
    }
}
```

but the Xcode alarm method does not override any method from its superclass. If I write as:

```swift
func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker)
```

There is no alarm, but when I execute the code, the programming never runs into this function.